# how to prevent special charactors in ion-input .?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic5

special characters are accepting in input field . i am using the field for storing the serial number.
serial number is alphanumeric

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="serial_number" (ngModelChange)="validation($event)" #serialno  id="serialno"  class="cac-input"></ion-input>
```

```
  validation(event) {
    const inputElement = document.getElementById('serialno') as HTMLInputElement;
    const pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
    console.log(event)
    console.log(pattern.test(event))
    let c = event.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '');
    inputElement.value = '';
    inputElement.value = c;
    console.log(c)
    this.serial_number = c;
  }
```

i previously used regex for removing the special characters....but after removing also the value is shown in input field...

i need to prohibit special characters from entering in input field.

in browser , using (keypress) event working fine....but in android (keypress) event is not working

[In app the field shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r6xn.png)

[consoling the ngmodel field shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRRDC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write a validator for this, it takes an input regex which it validates for valid and invalid characters, then we do the replace of the unwanted characters with empty string, we also need to lookout for paste events where if invalid characters are pasted they also need to be cleaned, this all can be done using the `@HostListener` property on events `keydown` and `paste`!

directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appPattern]',
})
export class PatternDirective {
  @Input() appPattern: string = '[A-Za-z0-9]';

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) public onKeydown(event: any) {
    const value: string = event.target.value;
    if (!value) {
      return true;
    }
    const regExpr = new RegExp(`^(${this.appPattern})+$`);
    if (!regExpr.test(value)) {
      event.target.value = value.replace(
        new RegExp(`(${this.appPattern})|.*`, 'gm'),
        '$1'
      );
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event']) public onPaste(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let clipboardText = event.clipboardData.getData('text');
    event.target.value = clipboardText.replace(
      new RegExp(`(${this.appPattern})|.*`, 'gm'),
      '$1'
    );
  }
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}
}
```

html

```
 <ion-input
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="todo.title1"
    name="title1"
    appPattern="[A-Za-z0-9]"
  ></ion-input>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3zkjat?file=pages%2Fpattern.directive.ts,pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: still facing issue.....when we type a special character it display's ,after only typing another character removes the special character , also the new typed character also removed

eg :

abcd string
adding $ to it , it display (abcd$)
now adding h to the string , it removes the $ from string as well as h 
result = (abcd)

Comment: @shahid does this answer solve your issue?

Comment: yes buddy..it did.....for now...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ionic provides an easy one liner using the supoorted [pattern](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#pattern) attribute on ion-input:

```
<ion-input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" ></ion-input>
```